# PHP e-mail form with ReCAPTCHA

Tags: php, security, form, email, captcha

I want to ask if you can review the code for a simple contact form and the PHP code which sends me an email once a visitor fills the form and is validated through Recaptcha

On my index.php file here are the form and php code

HTML:

```
<form id="contactform" action="index.php#contact" method="post" class="form" role="form">

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control required" id="vname" name="vname" placeholder="Your Name" type="text" required />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control required" id="vemail" name="vemail" placeholder="Your Email" type="email" required />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control required" id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Your Message" rows="7" required></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="GOOGLE PUBLIC KEY"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-send" value="Send">
    </div>  

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  $captcha;
    if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) { $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']; }
  // Check for correct reCAPTCHA
    $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=GOOGLE SECRET KEY&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if (!$captcha || $response.success == false) {
        echo "Your CAPTCHA response was wrong";
        exit ;
      } else {
        // Check for Blank Fields..
        if ($_POST["vname"] == "" || $_POST["vemail"] == "" || $_POST["msg"] == "") {
    echo "Please fill all required fields";
} else {
    // Check if the "Sender's Email" input field is filled out
    $email = $_POST['vemail'];
    // Sanitize E-mail Address
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    // Validate E-mail Address
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if (!$email) {
        echo "Invalid Sender's Email";
    } else {
        $to = 'myemail@mail.com';
        $subject = 'New Form Entry';
        $message = "New message was submitted from <br /> " . "<strong>" . $_POST['vname'] . "</strong>" . "<br /><br />The message is:<br />" . "<strong>" . $_POST['msg'] . "</strong>";
        $headers = "From:" . $_POST['vname'] . "<" . $email . ">";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        // Sender's Email
        // Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
        $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
        // Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            echo "Your mail has been sent successfully!";
        } else {
            echo "Failed to send email, try again.";
            exit ;
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

The only function of this is to send me an email and it works as I want it, but I am not aware if this form is secure?

Is it possible that someone can exploit this code and upload a shell, or do any other sort of attack against my site.

Answer (score 2):

Since `$_POST['vname']` is not escaped, your mail script is vulnerable to a header-splitting attack [like this](/a/43091/9357).  A cleverly crafted name could be used to make your script CC any arbitrary recipient and thus send spam.